# Handling Session timeout on client

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, session

I want to handle session time out on client. Currently, we are not handling sessions time out in our asp.net MVC code. Is there any trick I can use, to just show an alert box when session expires on all ajax requests? Say my session time out is 20 minutes. Is there any way, I can achieve it on client using `jquery` instead of handling this on server?

Where and how should I check for session timeout using jquery?

Comment: The Session data is stored on server. So you will need to go to server to check session expiration.

Comment: Im using StateServer mode, will i be notified when session ends?

Comment: @Dandy say I know my Session will expire after 20 minutes. Do I still need to go to server to check for its expiry? Or is there way I can do it in jquery too knowing my session will always expire after every 20 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via cookie and setTimout() . I have tried this in my project.

I followed two steps:

## Saved my login time in cookie when the user logs in

```
$.cookie("login-time", 'your-login-time');
```

## Use setTimeout() to check the your login time expires

```
setTimeout(function(){
    var login-time = $.cookie("login-time");
    // add 20 minutes to login-time
    //get current time and compare it with login-time and produce alert
}, 1000);
```